# Problems with matrix indexing using for loop and if condition

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop, matrix, indexing

I to do some indexing, something like what follows:

```
for c=1:size(params,1)
    for d=1:size(data,2)
        if params(c,8)==1
            value1(c,d)=data(params(c,11),d);
        elseif params(c,8)==2
            value2(c,d)=data(params(c,11),d);
        elseif params(c,8)==3
            value3(c,d)=data(params(c,11),d);
        end
    end
end
```

The problems with this is that if we have `params(:,8)=1,3,1,3,2,3,1...` then **value1** will contain all zeros in rows 2, 4, 5, 6, etc. These are the rows that do not have 1 in column 8 in `params`. Similarly, **value2** will contains all zeros in rows 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7... and **value3** will contain all zeros in row  1, 3, 5, 7, .... Could anyone tell me how to index so I don't have 'gaps' of zeros in between rows? Thanks!

Edit; below is a sample dataset:

**data** (1080x15 double)

```
168 432 45  86
170 437 54  82
163 423 52  83
178 434 50  84
177 444 42  87
177 444 58  85
175 447 48  77
184 451 59  86
168 455 52  104
174 437 62  88
175 443 55  85
179 456 51  92
168 450 73  82
175 454 60  68
```

**params** (72x12 double - we are interested in only column 8 and 11 ) so I'm showing only column 8-11 for the sake of space:

```
1   10  15  1
3   12  16  16
2   10  15  32
3   12  16  47
1   8   14  63
2   10  15  77
2   8   14  92
3   10  15  106
1   12  16  121
3   8   14  137
2   10  15  151
```

The expected output for **value1, value2, and value3** should be 24x15. This is because there are 15 columns in data and value 1, 2, 3 occur 24 times each in column 8 in `params`.

Comment: I think you need to pad with something if not zeros and somewhere if not into the gaps. How about assume a minimal `data` and show us the expected outputs - value1, value2, value3?

Comment: Can you post a sample data set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `bsxfun` to avoid for-loop (note that it is actually not vertorizing):

```
value1 = bsxfun(@times,data(params(:,11),:),(params(:,8)==1));
value2 = bsxfun(@times,data(params(:,11),:),(params(:,8)==2));
value3 = bsxfun(@times,data(params(:,11),:),(params(:,8)==3));
```

But it still gives you the results with zero rows. So you can remove zero-rows by:

```
value1(all(value1==0,2),:)=[];
value2(all(value2==0,2),:)=[];
value3(all(value3==0,2),:)=[];
```

You can also use above commands to remove zero-rows in your results without using `bsxfun`. It is not always good to loose the transparency.

Comment: Thank you. I thought about removing zeros. If I use `value1(all(value1==0,2),:)=[];` does that mean it only remove the row if all the values in the row are zeros? when I tested it, it seems to be the case. It's possible that I may have zero as values for some cells (but not all) in certain rows.

Comment: yes, it will remove only the rows that contain ALL zero. If a row has some zeros, some non-zeros, then it will still be there.